# In-memory event sourcing algorithm - is it right? is it threadsafe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, event-sourcing

Apologies for the slightly speculative nature of this question.

I am writing a Cms using an in-memory static object to hold the current state of the system, and am using Event Sourcing to create an event log which I can use to rebuild the object state, and to provide roll back etc. (see http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html if you have no idea what I am on about)

```
public class Cms
{
    private static object WriteLock = new object();
    public static Cms Read { get; set; }
    static Cms Write { get; set; }

    static Cms()
    {
        Read = RebuildFromActionLog();
        Write = RebuildFromActionLog();
    }

    public static void Update(Action action)
    {

        lock (WriteLock)
        {                
            try
            {
                action.Apply(Write);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Write = RebuildFromActionLog(); //ditch the potentially messed up Write model
                throw;
            }
            LogAction(action); //the action was a keeper, so keep it
            Read = Write; //ditch the current read only model - it will continue to be used by any requests that have grabbed it
            Write = RebuildFromActionLog(); //get a new model ready for the next write
        }
    }
...
}
```

Aside from the potential for lots of writes to stack up if execution or rebuilding takes a long time, and the potential for lots of memory to be used, are there any bugs in this, particularly concurrency related bugs?

Comment: Are you sure no thread goes for starvetion mode? Becase the lock{} block should not take up much time consuming work.
Also, if one thread has aquired alock and its catch block has thrown an exception, your throwing it in catch{} block. So do you think the lock will be ever released??

Comment: hmm maybe this would be better as a concurrent list or something, and let the actions queue up in there... good point! I think the exceptions are safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639493/in-c-how-can-i-safely-exit-a-lock-with-a-try-catch-block-inside

Comment: Since he is throwing from catch, the lock is never released i guess. Correct me if i am wrong :)
Also if a thread throws an exception, the app will crash.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem if someone uses the public getter or setter of `Read`, as you have no synchronization there. If someone uses that property at the same time as another thread modifies it in `Update` the read could fetch a stale value, or a change made by writing could be silently lost.

Does that property really need to be public? And publicly *writeable*?

Comment: defs not writeable - though I am wondering if it should be volatile. It needs to be public so the rest of the app can get it's hands on it, right? maybe it should be a volatile private field with a public getter...

Comment: @mcintye321: If you want to be able to read/write to it from different threads without synchronization then yes it should be marked as volatile. See the docs for `volatile`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx But even with `volatile` you still have some possibly unwanted race conditions.